# How to programmatically refresh wpf c#?

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, observablecollection

I have this scenario well, i'll let the model explain.

```
public class ScheduleMonthlyPerDayModel 
{
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }

    public string Day 
    { 
        get
        {
            return Date.Day.ToString();
        }
    }

    ObservableCollection<AppointmentDTO> _appointments;
    public ObservableCollection<AppointmentDTO> Appointments 
    {
        get
        {
            return _appointments;
        }
        set
        {
            _appointments = value;

            if (value.Count > 0)
                NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => HasSchedule);
        }
    }

    public bool BelongsToCurrentMonth
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public bool HasSchedule
    {
        get
        {
            return _appointments.Count > 0 ? true : false;
        }
    }

    public ScheduleMonthlyPerDayModel()
    {
        _appointments = new ObservableCollection<AppointmentDTO>();
    }

    public void ClearCollection()
    {
        _appointments.Clear();
    }
}

public class ScheduleMonthlyPerWeekModel
{
    public ScheduleMonthlyPerDayModel Sunday{get; set;}

    public ScheduleMonthlyPerDayModel Monday{get; set;}

    public ScheduleMonthlyPerDayModel Tuesday{get; set;}

    public ScheduleMonthlyPerDayModel Wednesday{get; set;}

    public ScheduleMonthlyPerDayModel Thursday{get; set;}

    public ScheduleMonthlyPerDayModel Friday{get; set;}

    public ScheduleMonthlyPerDayModel Saturday{get; set;}
}
```

The bindings to xaml are working with a glimpse of the xaml like this:

`headereditemscontrol itemsSource= weekcollection`, where weekcollection is an object of `schedulemonthlyperweekmodel`.

Inside that headereditemscontrol I have templated each day for each property of the schedulemonthlyperweekmodel as follows:

```
<Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <ColumnDefinition />
    <ColumnDefinition />
</Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
<Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
    <RowDefinition Height="*" />
</Grid.RowDefinitions>
<TextBlock Grid.Row="0"  Style="{StaticResource CalendarDates}" Text="{Binding Path=Saturday.Day}" />
<ListBox Grid.Row="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Padding="0" 
         ItemsSource="{Binding Path= Saturday.Appointments}"
         ItemTemplate="{StaticResource myItemStyle}"
         Visibility="{Binding Path=Saturday.HasSchedule, Converter={StaticResource BoolToVisibilityConverter}}" />
```

Basically, I'm trying to achieve a monthly view with each day having a collection of appointments. My problem is that when I programmatically add items to the, for example here, saturday.appointments collection, through debug appending of items is a success and notifying the main collection(weekcollection), does not refresh the UI.

What I would like to achieve is: after I add the supposed appointment to its corresponding day/dates, the user interface will also update accordingly, but how do I do that?

Currently, the UI only updates if I change/toggle to different then back, after that the appointments are shown nicely. I would like to automate it, as it is ugly to require a user to toggle to something else then back before they can see the appointments list.

Comment: What is `NotifyOfPropertyChange` and I don't see INotifyPropertyChanged implemented.

Comment: If you are binding the DataSource of the control you shouldn't have to "Refresh" anything.

Comment: Right now if you add an item to the Appointments collection, it should automatically show that item in the ListBox.  However, the Visibility binding does not update when the list goes from empty to filled.  Is this true?

Comment: yes true @Moozhe, that is why i guess i need to toggle off the current view to other view then back to make the listbox visible. so how should i proceed? would it be, performance-wise better to just leave out the visibility code? and i try to toggle off view then back programmatically, but it's ugly and i wish to have a better course of action. @ nickbabcock it is inherited by schedulemonthlyperdaymodel, apparently i deleted the inheritance accidentally. thank you.

Comment: just an additional, i can go away with the listbox visibility, it will work and display the appointments, but i also have datatriggers set to HasSchedule property which will change the cells background when it has appointments, so i think that deals with the same problem, how to reflect the changes in the inner/secondary properties to xaml to update the user interface.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with your Visibility is that it's binding to a readonly property which calculates a value on **get**.  Therefore, there is no way for it to notify that it has changed.

Your HasSchedule property needs to know when the Appointment property changes.  The setter for the Appointment property only knows when the entire list changes.  In your case you need to know when the *contents* of the list changes.

**ObservableCollection** has an event which tells you when the contents of the list changes, called **CollectionChanged**.  You should do the following to notify that your HasSchedule property has changed using this event:

```
ObservableCollection<AppointmentDTO> _appointments;
public ObservableCollection<AppointmentDTO> Appointments
{
    get
    {
        return _appointments;
    }
    set
    {
        if (_appointments != value)
        {
            if (_appointments != null)
                _appointments.CollectionChanged -= Appointments_CollectionChanged;

            _appointments = value;

            if (PropertyChanged != null)
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("HasSchedule"));

            if (_appointments != null)
                _appointments.CollectionChanged += Appointments_CollectionChanged;
        }
    }
}

void Appointments_CollectionChanged(object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (PropertyChanged != null)
        PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("HasSchedule"));
}
```

This is assuming, as you have said, you have implemented INotifyPropertyChanged in your ViewModel.  In this case, every time your collection changes in some way, it notifies that the HasSchedule property has changed.  The binding will refresh the value and update the visibility if it has changed.

Comment: mistake on my end. the propertychanged is instantiated like this: public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged = delegate { }; from viewmodelbase.

Comment: tried the code and instead of using my previous Viewmodelbase inheritance, i changed it with INotifyPropertyChanged, recompiled then test again, the listbox still didn't show after the appointments were added.

Comment: another thing, i checked after adding one item to appointments collection if the hasschedule value changes, it does, so i guess the problem is that, the new bool value does not reflect or refreshes the xaml.

Comment: your explanation clarified the problem. even the HasSchedule property changes value,to true, when i fill the appointments of the schedulemonthlyperdaymodel, i don't understand why it did not reflect to xaml. So i tried another approach where i made a simple method in the model(schedulemonthlyperdaymodel) to append items to the appointmentcollection then notify the hasschedule property, the solution worked and refreshes the xaml as i wanted. thank you @Moozhe

Comment: Glad to be of help.  I'm not sure why that wasn't working as is.  It's possible that HasSchedule isn't notifying of change when you change the entire Appointments list.  I added 2 lines of code to my example above, where it calls PropertyChanged during the Appointments setter.  Maybe that will make your code more compact and succinct.

Answer (score 3):

As Nick suggested, using the INotifyPropertyChanged interface is key.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged.aspx

If you want the ObsCollection to be aware of property changes, you have to implement this interface as displayed in the link above. This will update the UI control that it's bound to when something is added, removed or changed. Without it, you'd actually have to track the changes in code and update them manually.

It's actually really easy to implement and use and it's freaking AWESOME. If you don't want to use this, you may have well as just used a winform. =)

Hope this helps.

Comment: yes my mistake really. as mentioned above i have inherited from a class which implements inotify. i was probably sleepy and deleted it accidently without noticing, the ScheduleMonthlyPerDayModel actually looks like this "public class ScheduleMonthlyPerDayModel : ViewModelBase",where the viewmodelbase inherits from inotifypropertychanged. really sorry for not noticing missing code.